# wp7 xna gestures not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to use the drag gesture in my code. But unfortunately it's not working.The following is the code snippet I am using. Is there any problem with it? If so help me.

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.DragComplete | GestureType.Tap | GestureType.Pinch | GestureType.FreeDrag;
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

    if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.DragComplete)
    {
        // do something                
    }
}
```

Comment: whats not working? tried debugging?

Comment: Drag event not getting detected!

Answer (score 0):

```
 TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap | GestureType.DragComplete;
            foreach (GestureSample gestureSample in input.Gestures)
            {
                if (gestureSample.GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("tapped  ");
                }
                else if (gestureSample.GestureType == GestureType.DragComplete)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("dragged");
                }
            }
```